# Fill DIV sides with bg color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to fill up the both sides of a div (with a background image) that is child of a full-width div.

[Image background that needs color fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JJob.png)

So, the blue on the image above is a background image and I need to color fill the "gap" on the sides without cover the tranparency of the backgroung image. How to accomplish that with CSS?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="footer-decoration" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

And heres is my current CSS/Sass:

```
#footer-decoration {
    margin-top: $grid-gutter-width;

    >.container {
        background: url('../img/bg-footer-top.png') center center;
        background-color: transparent;
        height: 50px;
    }
}
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3, by the way.

Thanks for any help folks!

Comment: create one image what you want you achieve so that it can help us to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill the sides by applying a background color to the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements of the container.

```css
body {
  background: url('//i.imgur.com/7QboUH0.png') repeat;
}

#footer-decoration > .container {
  background: url('//i.imgur.com/LVKQVf1.png') no-repeat;
  height: 55px;
  position: relative;
}

#footer-decoration > .container:after, #footer-decoration > .container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
#footer-decoration > .container:after {
  left: -100%;
  right: 100%;
}

#footer-decoration > .container:before {
  right: -100%;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div id="footer-decoration">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```